# Azure Management API not returning Reserved Instances

Tags: azure-api-management

I have a couple of reserved instances that I'd like to be notified about when its close to their expiry. By default, the purchaser gets notified about expiration through an email, but I'd like to manage that notification myself, by injecting a work item in our ISMS when it gets close to that time (or 1/4/8/12 weeks beforehand).

I have:

- Created a Logic App
- Enabled System Assigned Managed Identity on it
- Granted this MI the Reservation Reader role. If I check the Role Assignments on the Reservations, as well as the Reservation Orders, the MI is listed under Reservation Readers

As a test, the Logic App does an HTTP call to https://management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Capacity/reservationOrders?api-version=2019-04-01. The call passes with a 200.

However... the results are empty:

[image]

If I modify the HTTP request to return a *specific* Reservation (and not try and List the Reservation Orders), I *do* get the details of that Reservation (I get the Reservation Order ID through the Azure Portal, then call to GET [https://management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Capacity/reservationOrders/{reservationOrderId}/reservations/{reservationId}?api-version=2019-04-01](https://management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Capacity/reservationOrders/%7BreservationOrderId%7D/reservations/%7BreservationId%7D?api-version=2019-04-01)).

I have also confirmed that the MI has the Read permissions on each Reservation Order (by clicking through to them from the Reservation).

I have also (being at wits' end) added the MI to the Reservation Administrators. No joy.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to have been resolved in the latest version of the API. If I query Microsoft Graph using API version 2022-11-01, I get results.